# iOS 12 Safari: Is there a way to make web-based QR Scanning work?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, promise, mobile-safari

There are a few working examples of web-based QR scanners out there, notably [Instascan](https://schmich.github.io/instascan/) ([repo](https://github.com/schmich/instascan)) and [JsQRScanner](https://jbialobr.github.io/JsQRScanner/) ([repo](https://github.com/jbialobr/JsQRScanner)). Both of these work flawlessly on Android. On Safari with iOS 12 on an iPhone however, both the examples and my code fails horrendously, producing a black box where the video feed should be or nothing at all. I have no way to debug this without a mac, since I can't catch javascript promises if I have no access to the promise object.

I tried both of these libraries [and I even communicated with one of the developers](https://github.com/jbialobr/JsQRScanner/issues/3), but logs would simplify the process. I can't produce these logs without proper tools on Safari.

Is there any way to make things work properly on Safari?

Here's a part of my JsQRScanner code. I also kept my old InstaScan code, in case anyone needs it.

```
/**
 * Sets up the QR scanner.
 * this function will be called when JsQRScanner is ready to use
 * @see https://github.com/jbialobr/JsQRScanner
 */
function JsQRScannerReady() {
    try {
        //create a new scanner passing to it a callback function that will be invoked when
        //the scanner succesfully scan a QR code
        var jbScanner = new JsQRScanner(scanEvent);
        setResult("Constructed JsQRScanner object.");
        //reduce the size of analyzed images to increase performance on mobile devices
        jbScanner.setSnapImageMaxSize(300);
        setResult("setSnapImageMaxSize completed.");
        var scannerParentElement = document.getElementById("videoBoundingBox");
        if (scannerParentElement) {
            //append the jbScanner to an existing DOM element
            jbScanner.appendTo(scannerParentElement);
            setResult("Appended jbScanner to div.");
        }   
    } catch (e) {
        setResult("Caught exception in the camera initialisation.");
        setResult(e.message);
    }
    setResult("initialisation complete.");
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed that this barcode scanner works, at least in Safari itself, as long as it's not in a PWA. https://github.com/code-kotis/barcode-scanner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After an [extensive conversation](https://github.com/jbialobr/JsQRScanner/issues/3) with the developer of [JsQRScanner](https://github.com/jbialobr/JsQRScanner), we were able to make QR Scanning work on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

The black box described in the question suggests that this problem is solved by the answers on this Stackoverflow question:

[Accessing the camera in iOS Safari on an iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68797537/accessing-the-camera-in-ios-safari-on-an-iphone)

The proposed fix there is to add this to the video element:

```
// Fix for iOS Safari from https://leemartin.dev/hello-webrtc-on-safari-11-e8bcb5335295
video.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
video.setAttribute('muted', '');
```

video.setAttribute('playsinline', '')