# Accessing the camera in iOS Safari on an iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari, camera

I have *Single Page Webapp* (SPA) that *verifies* the users as part of the signup process. Part of the verification is to capture a *selfie* of the user. To this end, I've implemented a version of the following code to get the *camera* input into a `video` element on the webpage, from which I can then *sample* images into a `canvas`.

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
    .then(localMediaStream => {
      if ('srcObject' in video) {
        video.srcObject = localMediaStream;
      } else {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
      }
      video.play();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(`Not available!!!!`, err);
    });
```

This code is based on an example by Wes Bos, from his JavaScript30 course (#19 Unreal Webcam Fun). You can try it out [here](https://codepen.io/s5b/project/editor/ZmqneL).

This code appears to work fine on most browsers, with the ***major*** exception of Apple Safari on iOS on an iPhone (example: iPhone 12 Pro, iOS 14.7.1). On the iPhone I get the first frame of the camera image captured and there after, the `video` element displays a black square.

Oddly, it works fine on an iPad (example: iPad Pro (11-inch), iOS 14.7.1), but not on any iPhone that I've tried.

I've seen a lot of discussion here on StackOverflow and elsewhere describing similar issues, but I'm yet to find a definitive answer, or better yet, a solution.

Does anybody have any idea?

Cheers,  S t u a r t .

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @TalalZahid : Thanks for your interest. I've added a response below with the solution that finally came my way. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I posted this question on other services and eventually received a response a user named ***Ravavyr*** through a separate Discord channel. The response pointed me to this article which provided an answer.

https://leemartin.dev/hello-webrtc-on-safari-11-e8bcb5335295

It appears that iOS Safari needs some more configuration to make it work.

The [CodePen](https://codepen.io/s5b/project/editor/ZmqneL) linked from the original post has been updated to include the changes that make it work.

```
// Fix for iOS Safari from https://leemartin.dev/hello-webrtc-on-safari-11-e8bcb5335295
video.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
video.setAttribute('muted', '');
video.setAttribute('playsinline', '')
```

I hope this helps future readers.